# android tools update always erases extra libraries

Tags: android, ant, adb, adt

updating ADT every so often, always deletes or overwrites libraries I have added to the android folders.

I use additional libraries with `ant` so that it recognizes more useful commands, these always get overwritten on update and break my scripts. How can I avoid this, while still updating my tools, and/or protect certain files?

Comment: What are "the android folders"? If you mean the SDK installation, that is a singularly lousy place for you to put your own libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I have them stored in other places, so that I can copy them back in after they get overwritten, but it is made pretty clear that my ant expansion jars need to be in the same folder as ant. And the Android dev tool updates also update ant, so I wouldn't want to move that would I

Comment: What evidence do you have that updating the Android SDK updates Ant? It has never updated Ant on my Linux box -- I'm still at the Ant 1.8.1 I installed a long time ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare updating the Android Development Toolkit erases files in the platform-tools folder and other tools folders under its installation directory that I have added, such as `ant-contrib-0.6`

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of Java developers who are capable of using Ant without storing Ant inside of the Android SDK. Many of them don't even *have* the Android SDK. Yet, magically, Ant still works. Please store Ant and related materials somewhere *outside the Android SDK*, and you will not have this problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare good for them, my ant came with the android development toolkit and actually has instructions or at least a readme about what folder inside the adt they moved it too. It didn't come with instructions for moving it outside of that, if thats the answer, then elaborate on that answer because this thread isn't about other java developers its about the structure of the adt

Comment: The only Ant that ADT distributes is one buried in an Eclipse plugin. You can tell this by downloading and examining the Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). That copy of Ant is not designed for independent use, but rather solely by that Eclipse plugin. You are welcome to provide evidence to the contrary. Otherwise, please install Ant the way everybody else does, via http://ant.apache.org or your favorite distribution mechanism (e.g., Linux distro package manger). Then, store Ant add-ons and such following Ant's instructions and outside of your Android SDK.